# How do I store agents in a block untill a transporter can move them?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to use a block as to represent a storage area for items to be used in an assembly, I am using the delay block with  delay time of 0, but maybe the queue block would be more appropriate? I have set up a model in which every X number of seconds a "truck" arrives and if the delay block contains less than a specified capacity of elements, the inject function is called to refill the block. This sort of works, but is seems that the agents are flowing through the delay block's out port and thus do not count toward its capacity (that makes sense to me...) resulting in my source blocks continuing to create agents when the system isn't ready for them. My delay block is followed by a "move by transporter" block which seems to be getting all of the delay blocks outputs immediately. There are only two transporters in my model and I am not sure why more than two agents can be accepted by the transporter block at a time. I set my transporter fleet to have a capacity of 2 but that did not solve the problem.

My goal is to have an essentially unlimited pool of parts at the inlet of the factory, but only create agents when the downstream processes are able to pull them in.

Answer (score 0):

Best use a "Wait" block here:

Let your trucks dump stuff into "Wait" whenever they arrive. Your downstream block can now pull them when they are ready using `myWaitBlock.free(someAgent` for as many agents as they want to pull from it.

Similarly, you can use a Delay with infinite capacity and set its type to "Until stopDelay() is called". Then similarly as the "Wait" block, you call `myDelayBlock.stopDelay(someAgent)` when you want.

Another option: Use a hold-block in front of a normal (infinite) queue and unblock it when ready: `myHoldBlock.unBlock(numToLetThrough)` --> probably the easiest